# Download tables into separate sheets

Tags: php, excel

```
<?php 
require "connection.php";
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
$date= date("m/d/Y");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">

<style>
.container{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
 table, th,td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.panel-primary{
    width:200%;
}
.table{
    width: auto !important;
}
.panel-danger{
    width: 60%;
}
.hbp{
    width: 100% !important;
}
.rsvp{
    width: 50% !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<title>Admin Reports</title>
<div class="container">
<h1 style= "padding-bottom:10px;">Daily Reports</h1>
<!-- BEGIN COLD -->
<div class="row">
                <div class="panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Cold</h3>
                    </div>
<table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
<?php 
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW columns FROM `call`"); 
// Loop over all result rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($row["Field"] == 'id')
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<th>';
    echo $row["Field"];
    echo '</th>';
    }


?>
</tr>
</thead>

  <tbody>
<?php 
$query2= "SELECT * from `call` WHERE `Date` = '$date'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $fieldname => $values)
        {
            if($fieldname == 'id')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td>';
                echo $values;
                echo '</td>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
}

?>    
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- END COLD -->

<!-- BEGIN COMM -->

                <div class="panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Com</h3>
                    </div>
<table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
<?php 
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW columns FROM `com`"); 
// Loop over all result rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($row["Field"] == 'id')
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<th>';
    echo $row["Field"];
    echo '</th>';
    }


?>
</tr>
</thead>

  <tbody>
<?php 
$query2= "SELECT * from `com` WHERE `Date` = '$date'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $fieldname => $values)
        {
            if($fieldname == 'id')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td>';
                echo $values;
                echo '</td>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
}

?>    
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- END COM -->
```

I want that instead of them displaying, when I click on "generate report" an excel file downloads with each table on a separate sheets? Is this possible? I read about it but I couldn't seem to figure out how it is done.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data